# Entity Framework 4: Create a new Entity, save it, no errors, and no record inserted?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, persistence

EDIT: Better yet, I do this with no errors and no records inserted:

```
var myTopLevelEntity = _DC.TopLevelEntity.Where( p => p.ID = 1).First();
var newEntity = new Entity();
newEntity.pocofield = ""; // set all primary keys and poco fields
newEntity.TopLevelEntity = myTopLevelEntity;
_DC.Entitys.Add( newEntity);
```

I checked SQL server's profiler.  No commands other than a select happened during that time.

(END EDIT)

I have a set of Entities to add at once, all new.  They are dependent on a record in another table.  I do the following:

```
var myTopLevelEntity = _DC.TopLevelEntity.Where( p => p.ID = 1).First();
```

NewEntity has a hierarchy:

```
newEntity.A[].pocofields
newEntity.B[].pocofields
newEntity.C[].pocofields
newEntity.C[].D[].pocofields
```

So, I do this

```
var newEntity = new Entity();
newEntity.pocofield = ""; // various poco fields, set all keys

var A = new AEntity();
A.pocofield = ""; // various poco fields, set all keys
newEntity.As.Add( A);

var B = new BEntity();
B.pocofield = ""; // various pocos, set all keys
newEntity.Bs.Add( B);

var C = new CEntity();
C.pocofield = "";  // various, set all keys
var D = new DEntity();
D.pocofield = ""; // various, set all keys
C.Ds.Add( D);
newEntity.Cs.Add( C);

newEntity.TopLevelEntitys.Add( myTopLevelEntity);
_DC.Entitys.Add( newEntity);
```

At this point, no errors occur (I don't have `try/catch` anywhere).  No records show up in the database either.  What am I doing incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to call `_DC.SaveChanges`